# How do you use bindCallback with a function that contains a success and error callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am trying to wrap Ionic File.moveTo so it can be an observable.  It has the following signature

```
moveTo(parent: DirectoryEntry, newName?: string, successCallback?: EntryCallback, errorCallback?: ErrorCallback): void;
```

But the bindCallback only expects a success call back.  I am trying with this, but I can't seem to get it to work

```
const movedFile$ = bindCallback(fileEntry.moveTo).call(this.file.tempDirectory, fileEntry.name + "_scaled.jpg") as Observable<Entry>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`bindNodeCallback`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/adbe65e659bbf17f6ab20a9b30fcca0e4d76af9a/src/internal/observable/bindCallbackInternals.ts#L73-L84). Its callback function has the error as the first argument.

```js
(...results: any[]) => {
  if (isNodeStyle) {
    const err = results.shift();
    if (err != null) {
      subject.error(err);
      return;
    }
```

As you can see, if an error occurs, you'll be able to intercept that in the `error` callback.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would consider to use `Observable` constructor to create a new Observable that manages the success and error callbacks.

I do not know how Ionic `File.moveTo` function works, but I have used this technique to wrap the `node` `fs` `readdir` function whose signature is

```
readdir(path: fs.PathLike, options: {
    encoding?: string;
    withFileTypes: true;
}, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, files: fs.Dirent[]) => void): void
```

In this case the wrapper function returns an Observable which emits the list of files in a directory or errors if an error occurs. The code of the wrapping function is this

```
function dirNamesListObs(fromDirPath: string) {
    return new Observable(
        (observer: Observer<string[]>): TeardownLogic => {
            readdir(fromDirPath, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
                if (err) {
                    observer.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                const dirs = files.filter(f => f.isDirectory()).map(d => d.name);
                observer.next(dirs);
                observer.complete();
            });
        },
    );
}
```

In you case the wrapping code could look something like this

```
function moveToObs(parent: DirectoryEntry, newName?: string) {
    return new Observable(
        (observer: Observer<any>): TeardownLogic => {
            moveTo(
              parent,
              newName, 
              res => {
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
              },
              err => observer.error(err)
            )
        }
    );
}
```

`bindCallback` and `bindNodeCallback` are probably not a good fit in this case, since both these functions expect to wrap functions with just ONE callback, while in your case you have to deal with TWO callbacks.